# ActiveRecord 2 level deep scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

Let's say post has_many comments
and comment belongs_to user

I want to get all users who have comments to this post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
 has_many :comments
 has_many :users, :through => :comments
```